# How to register FollowSymLinks in nginx?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, config, symlink

in the config file in the Apache site has this line:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

How do I register in the same config nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in your nginx conf file:

```
http {
    disable_symlinks off;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In nginx this option is by default. You can only [disable it](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks) if you want.